# How to reference 2 other pages (3 including the one I call the function on) in one query function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

This is the line of code I am trying to write:

```
=QUERY(Players!A:I, "select I where A = "&(Teams!A:F, "select A where F = '"&C2&"'"), 0)
```

Basically I am writing a query on 'Page1' that selects a name from column I on the 'Players' page where column A (also on the 'Players' page) = column A on the 'Teams' page where F = cell C2 on 'Page1'. There is a lot of referencing different pages which might make this confusing to understand. Also, the line of code is returning a formula parse error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try perhaps:

```
=QUERY(Players!A:I, "select I where A = '"&
 QUERY(Teams!A:F,   "select A where F = '"&C2&"'", 0)&"'", 0)
```

or:

```
=QUERY(Players!A:I, "select I where A = "&
 QUERY(Teams!A:F,   "select A where F = '"&C2&"'", 0), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second query is actually supposed to return a number so I changed the reference to the second query to "&QUERY(Teams!A:F, "select A where F = '"&C2&"'", 0), 0)